# How to request an API on bitcoin.de

Tags: python, bitcoin

Im new to python and I wanted to make a little python trading bot just as a side project but I have no idea how to request anything from bitcoin.de. You need a URL, a nonce, an api_key and an api_secret.

Thats what I got:

```
import json
import requests as rq

url = 'https://api.bitcoin.de/v4/account'
nonce = 0
api_key = 'Here_belongs_my_api_key'
api_secret = 'And_here_belongs_my_api_secret'
```

This is the documentation: https://www.bitcoin.de/de/api/tapi/doc#method_executeTrade (ONLY IN GERMAN).

Sadly, the doc is not telling how to do it in python and it doesnt work with

```
request = rq.get(url)
```

because it says access denied.

If someone could help me just get the current BTC price or my balance from it, you'd be a great help. Thanks!

Comment: always put full error message (starting at word "Traceback") in question (not in comments) as text (not screenshot, not link to external portal). There are other useful information.

Comment: do you want `executeTrade` or `balance` ? `executeTrade` needs `post()` instead of `get()`

Comment: You are only passing the url to the rq object. You will also need to pass the other paramaters.

Does this page help https://www.dataquest.io/blog/python-api-tutorial/

Comment: this API seems more complex then other APIs. In other APIs you would have to add values as `data=...` or `params=...` or `headers=...` but this API need to calculate special values using `SECRET KEY`, `md5`, `sha256`

Answer (score 1):

```
import json
import requests as rq

url = 'https://api.bitcoin.de/v4/account'
nonce = 0
api_key = 'Here_belongs_my_api_key'
api_secret = 'And_here_belongs_my_api_secret'
request = rq.post(url)
```

So I try to rewrite your code.